# $routeProvider.when('/', ...) has no effect, when html5 mode is on

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, route-provider

**Solution to the problem: url you write in base tag should have a trailing slash.**

I have the following routes configuration, but template is not requested, if html5 mode is on. No errors, no attempts to get the resource from the server.
Neither changing base url, nor setting prefix with `hasPrefix('!')` has no effect on this behavior

```
   angular
        .module('beneficiaryBanks')
        .config(configRoutes);

configRoutes.$inject = ['$routeProvider','$locationProvider'];
function configRoutes($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/',
        {
            controller: 'beneficiaryBanksListController',
            controllerAs: 'listVM',
            templateUrl: 'BeneficiaryBanksList.cshtml'
        });
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}
```

It  looks like angular does not match current url with '/'.

**update 1**
Debugging shows that for url `http://localhost:8080/APS/Home/BeneficiaryBanksModule` and base address `APS/Home/BeneficiaryBanksModule` angular sees route as `/BeneficiaryBanksModule` which does not match with `/`, whereas route becomes just a `/` when html5 mode is disabled.

Comment: Is it running on a web server?

Comment: @GabrielCâmara In debug mode, locally, iis express

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in base tag. If it does not end with slash `/` angular treats last part as a file name and drops it.

That's why I saw `/BeneficiaryBanksModule` instead of `/`

Answer (score 2):

As I could see [here](https://dzone.com/articles/fixing-html5mode-and-angular), there are some configurations that you may have to do in order to achieve this combination of AngularJS and IIS Express with html5 mode activated.

I don't know if you read this article, but there are a few tips to make it work.

Answer (score 2):

That's because your request is handled by server itself, but not by your angular app.

Try to read some articles about how to setup your server to work with html5 mode:

https://dzone.com/articles/fixing-html5mode-and-angular
http://www.thinkovator.com/blog/post/angularjs-html5-mode-and-iis-rewrite/

Hope, it will help.

Comment: If the problem were at server side wouldn't I see the request for template in developer tools of a browser?

Comment: Not exactly, there will be no request for template if there's nothing to intercept the request

Comment: @GabrielCâmara Could you explain what do you mean by 'nothing to intercept'?

Comment: Of course! If your webserver doesn't have a mapping for the page you're requesting, then there'll be no request on server side. I'm not specialist in IIS, but that's something I've been through with Java. Sometimes I didn't have an url mapped, or had, but returning nothing. For me the problem is on server side, because the mapping in angularJS is correct.

Comment: @GabrielCâmara But I say about web browser's request at its side. Browser does not issue any request to the server. This is only for '/' path.

Comment: This is a request to the server `templateUrl: 'BeneficiaryBanksList.cshtml'`

Comment: @GabrielCâmara Yes, an it is not issued.